# Separate environment variables into different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, figaro-ruby

I'm drawing a blank. I'm trying to set environment variable in my Rails 6 app. I have installed figaro and can set variables like normal. But what I'm trying to do is set a default set of variables along with dev/staging/production.

I *think* it was something like:

```
# config/application.yml

defaults: 
  ...environment variables...

development: <<&defaults
  development variables...
production: <<&defaults
  production variables
```

I'm blanking on how to include the defaults for each environment and my google fu is failing me at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in some other posts dealing with environments

```
default: &defaults
# Environment variables

development: &development
  <<: *defaults
production:
  <<: *development
```